# Spark job finished, wrote output file but executor state is KILLED?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm trying to run an example from a book(Learning Spark by O'Reilly), it's just a simple a word count program. I submitted it, the output was written and it was correct, but in Spark master page

[image: the executor state was KILLED]

there is no error on stderr. although the output was correct, my trainer said I need to fix this problem so I've spent a few days but can't find any fix.

Here is the log

```
2018-07-31 17:52:49 INFO  CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend:2611 - Started daemon with process name: 3783@levanhuong
2018-07-31 17:52:49 INFO  SignalUtils:54 - Registered signal handler for TERM
2018-07-31 17:52:49 INFO  SignalUtils:54 - Registered signal handler for HUP
2018-07-31 17:52:49 INFO  SignalUtils:54 - Registered signal handler for INT
2018-07-31 17:52:49 WARN  Utils:66 - Your hostname, levanhuong resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 10.0.2.15 instead (on interface enp0s3)
2018-07-31 17:52:49 WARN  Utils:66 - Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
2018-07-31 17:52:50 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2018-07-31 17:52:50 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: levanhuong221
2018-07-31 17:52:50 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: levanhuong221
2018-07-31 17:52:50 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls groups to: 
2018-07-31 17:52:50 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls groups to: 
2018-07-31 17:52:50 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(levanhuong221); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(levanhuong221); groups with modify permissions: Set()
2018-07-31 17:52:51 INFO  TransportClientFactory:267 - Successfully created connection to /10.0.2.15:42475 after 186 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
2018-07-31 17:52:51 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: levanhuong221
2018-07-31 17:52:51 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: levanhuong221
2018-07-31 17:52:51 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls groups to: 
2018-07-31 17:52:51 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls groups to: 
2018-07-31 17:52:51 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(levanhuong221); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(levanhuong221); groups with modify permissions: Set()
2018-07-31 17:52:51 INFO  TransportClientFactory:267 - Successfully created connection to /10.0.2.15:42475 after 3 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
2018-07-31 17:52:51 INFO  DiskBlockManager:54 - Created local directory at /tmp/spark-2f1226a0-cace-4e98-b86e-c8a1106f9751/executor-4028ee6e-8aed-48fc-bd2f-5ed99efde94b/blockmgr-c7020392-e1bf-4551-b039-5b3eab7e2e08
2018-07-31 17:52:51 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - MemoryStore started with capacity 93.3 MB
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend:54 - Connecting to driver: spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@10.0.2.15:42475
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  WorkerWatcher:54 - Connecting to worker spark://Worker@10.0.2.15:35241
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  TransportClientFactory:267 - Successfully created connection to /10.0.2.15:35241 after 20 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  WorkerWatcher:54 - Successfully connected to spark://Worker@10.0.2.15:35241
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend:54 - Successfully registered with driver
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  Executor:54 - Starting executor ID 0 on host 10.0.2.15
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  Utils:54 - Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 42985.
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  NettyBlockTransferService:54 - Server created on 10.0.2.15:42985
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  BlockManager:54 - Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(0, 10.0.2.15, 42985, None)
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(0, 10.0.2.15, 42985, None)
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  BlockManager:54 - Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(0, 10.0.2.15, 42985, None)
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend:54 - Got assigned task 0
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend:54 - Got assigned task 1
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  Executor:54 - Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  Executor:54 - Running task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  Executor:54 - Fetching spark://10.0.2.15:42475/jars/Spark-1.0.jar with timestamp 1533034366863
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  TransportClientFactory:267 - Successfully created connection to /10.0.2.15:42475 after 4 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  Utils:54 - Fetching spark://10.0.2.15:42475/jars/Spark-1.0.jar to /tmp/spark-2f1226a0-cace-4e98-b86e-c8a1106f9751/executor-4028ee6e-8aed-48fc-bd2f-5ed99efde94b/spark-c6b95c11-80a9-495c-9503-29f4c1225caa/fetchFileTemp3888279004875803307.tmp
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  Utils:54 - Copying /tmp/spark-2f1226a0-cace-4e98-b86e-c8a1106f9751/executor-4028ee6e-8aed-48fc-bd2f-5ed99efde94b/spark-c6b95c11-80a9-495c-9503-29f4c1225caa/17384549101533034366863_cache to /usr/local/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/work/app-20180731175247-0012/0/./Spark-1.0.jar
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  Executor:54 - Adding file:/usr/local/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/work/app-20180731175247-0012/0/./Spark-1.0.jar to class loader
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  TorrentBroadcast:54 - Started reading broadcast variable 1
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  TransportClientFactory:267 - Successfully created connection to /10.0.2.15:40191 after 5 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
2018-07-31 17:52:52 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.8 KB, free 93.3 MB)
2018-07-31 17:52:53 INFO  TorrentBroadcast:54 - Reading broadcast variable 1 took 209 ms
2018-07-31 17:52:53 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 5.0 KB, free 93.3 MB)
2018-07-31 17:52:53 INFO  HadoopRDD:54 - Input split: file:/home/levanhuong221/01.txt:0+1650317
2018-07-31 17:52:53 INFO  HadoopRDD:54 - Input split: file:/home/levanhuong221/01.txt:1650317+1650318
2018-07-31 17:52:53 INFO  TorrentBroadcast:54 - Started reading broadcast variable 0
2018-07-31 17:52:53 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 22.9 KB, free 93.3 MB)
2018-07-31 17:52:53 INFO  TorrentBroadcast:54 - Reading broadcast variable 0 took 22 ms
2018-07-31 17:52:53 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 320.9 KB, free 93.0 MB)
2018-07-31 17:52:54 INFO  LineRecordReader:221 - Found UTF-8 BOM and skipped it
2018-07-31 17:52:55 INFO  Executor:54 - Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1). 1189 bytes result sent to driver
2018-07-31 17:52:55 INFO  Executor:54 - Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0). 1146 bytes result sent to driver
2018-07-31 17:52:55 INFO  CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend:54 - Got assigned task 2
2018-07-31 17:52:55 INFO  Executor:54 - Running task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2)
2018-07-31 17:52:55 INFO  MapOutputTrackerWorker:54 - Updating epoch to 1 and clearing cache
2018-07-31 17:52:55 INFO  TorrentBroadcast:54 - Started reading broadcast variable 2
2018-07-31 17:52:55 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - Block broadcast_2_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 26.2 KB, free 92.9 MB)
2018-07-31 17:52:55 INFO  TorrentBroadcast:54 - Reading broadcast variable 2 took 32 ms
2018-07-31 17:52:55 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - Block broadcast_2 stored as values in memory (estimated size 72.5 KB, free 92.9 MB)
2018-07-31 17:52:55 INFO  FileOutputCommitter:108 - File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
2018-07-31 17:52:55 INFO  MapOutputTrackerWorker:54 - Don't have map outputs for shuffle 0, fetching them
2018-07-31 17:52:55 INFO  MapOutputTrackerWorker:54 - Doing the fetch; tracker endpoint = NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark://MapOutputTracker@10.0.2.15:42475)
2018-07-31 17:52:55 INFO  MapOutputTrackerWorker:54 - Got the output locations
2018-07-31 17:52:56 INFO  ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator:54 - Getting 2 non-empty blocks out of 2 blocks
2018-07-31 17:52:56 INFO  ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator:54 - Started 0 remote fetches in 125 ms
2018-07-31 17:52:56 INFO  ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator:54 - Getting 2 non-empty blocks out of 2 blocks
2018-07-31 17:52:56 INFO  ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator:54 - Started 0 remote fetches in 1 ms
2018-07-31 17:52:56 INFO  FileOutputCommitter:535 - Saved output of task 'attempt_20180731175250_0006_m_000000_0' to file:/home/levanhuong221/output/master_url/_temporary/0/task_20180731175250_0006_m_000000
2018-07-31 17:52:56 INFO  SparkHadoopMapRedUtil:54 - attempt_20180731175250_0006_m_000000_0: Committed
2018-07-31 17:52:56 INFO  Executor:54 - Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2). 1545 bytes result sent to driver
2018-07-31 17:52:56 INFO  CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend:54 - Driver commanded a shutdown
2018-07-31 17:52:56 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend:43 - RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
utdown
```

edit: added spark job code

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
import scala.Tuple2;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class WordCount implements Serializable{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Op.Create a Java Spark Context
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("wordCount");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        // Load our input data.
        JavaRDD<String> input = sc.textFile(args[0]);
        // Split up into words.
        JavaRDD<String> words = input.flatMap(
                new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
                    public Iterator<String> call(String x) {
                        return Arrays.asList(x.split("\\W")).iterator();
                    }});
        // Transform into pairs and count.
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = words.mapToPair(
                new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>(){
                    public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String x){
                        return new Tuple2(x.toLowerCase(), 1);
                    }}).reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>(){
            public Integer call(Integer x, Integer y){ return x + y;}});
        // Save the word count back out to a text file, causing evaluation.
        counts.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile(args[1]);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us the Spark job code?

Comment: i added the code

Answer (score 2):

That error message appears to be normal and expected behaviour (though misleading in that it appears at ERROR level) according to the discussion on the Spark Jira for issue [SPARK-21733](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21733), which has been closed as "Not a problem".

One of the Spark developers states:

> "This is because executor is killed by NM with SIGTERM, this is quite
>   normal for Spark on YARN application, I don't think there's an issue
>   beside this error log. Everything will be cleaned out with shutdown
>   hook even SIGTERM received, so it should be fine like clean stop."

One of the other commenters suggests that you can avoid this error by setting

```
spark.network.timeout=420000
```

(though without explanation of why this helps - I have not tested it).